# Ubuntu Server (14.04 LTS) System-Wide Socks5 Auth Proxy

Tags: networking, server, 14.04, authentication, socks5

I have recently switched to the server version of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and am not aware of a way to apply a system-wide authentication socks5 proxy so that all traffic on that computer goes through the proxy. If you know of any sources or how-to-do-so's that would be very appreciated. Also using Private Internet Access (if that helps).

*This server is not running any GUI or managers, standalone terminal commands.

Answer (score 0):

Install [proxychains](https://github.com/rofl0r/proxychains-ng) with `sudo apt-get install proxychains`

And add the configuration for your current user:

`mkdir ~/.proxychains  # create this dir if not exists`

```
cat >> ~/.proxychains/proxychains.conf <<EOF
strict_chain
proxy_dns 
remote_dns_subnet 224
tcp_read_time_out 15000
tcp_connect_time_out 8000
localnet 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0
quiet_mode

[ProxyList]
socks5  127.0.0.1 1080    # proxy server
EOF
```

Now test it with: `proxychains4 curl http://www.askubuntu.com/`